# How to send email with Zend FrameWork 2 and Hostgator

Tags: email, zend-framework2, smtp, web-hosting

I've got a code I made myself for sending email using Zend Framework2 via gmail SMTP, my code works flawlessly in local host and in some free hosting sites but when running from Hostgator I get this:

```
File: vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mail/Protocol/AbstractProtocol.php:225

Message: Connection refused
```

This is my Code:

```php
use Zend\Mail\Transport\SmtpOptions;
use Zend\Mail\Message;
use Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp;

$options = new SmtpOptions(array(
    'name' => 'Gmail.com',
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'port'=> 587,
    'connection_class' => 'login',
    'connection_config' => array(
        'username' => 'user@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'password',
        'ssl'=> 'tls',
    ),
));



$message = new Message();
$message->addTo('him@gmail.com')
    ->addFrom('user@gmail.com')
    ->setEncoding("UTF-8")
    ->setSubject('test')
    ->setBody('test');

$transport = new Smtp();
$transport->setOptions($options);
$transport->send($message);
```

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Hostgator support and they solved my problem, the thing is hostgator servers does not allow smtp relay, so you just have to use an email account that exists within the hostgator server (one created for your domain I suggest). And thats all the problem was about :)